# Cassandra table - select query with where clause

Tags: cassandra, cql, bigdata

```
I am trying to create a table in Cassandra. 

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  password varchar,
  gender varchar,
  session_token varchar,
  state varchar,
  birth_year bigint
);
```

Now If I want to query the table username and password where my session_token = 1000001

```
Select user_name,password from users where session_token = 1000001;

Will this query work or do I have to create an index on session_token first and then do select query?
```

Comment: Is session_token is unique ?

Comment: Nope..It is not unique

Comment: Is is possible that for a single session_token there are multiple username ??

Comment: @AshrafulIslam : yes it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to first create index on it.**

Remember When not to use an index :

- On high-cardinality columns because you then query a huge volume of records for a small number of results
- On Low-cardinality column
- In tables that use a counter column
- On a frequently updated or deleted column
- To look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly queried. See Problems using an index to look for a row in a large partition unless narrowly queried below.

In your case `session_token` seems to be high cardinality column

It is best to create another table :

```
CREATE TABLE user_by_session (
    session_token varchar,
    user_name varchar,
    password varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY(session_token, user_name)
);
```

Now you can query :

```
SELECT user_name, password FROM user_by_session WHERE session_token = '1000001';
```

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html#concept_ds_sgh_yzz_zj